# 18.04 - I keep running out of space - how can I enlarge my partition?

Tags: partitioning

When I first installed Ubuntu I dual booted with awful disgusting windows and just decided this week to go pure Ubuntu. I love it however now I have a large formatted volume 500 gigs (where windows was, I formatted it in Linux) but my OS is only 20 gigs. I want to triple or quadruple my os partition and not lose any of my files.

Is there a way I can take space from the 500 gig partition and add it to my 20 gig os partition?

Comment: I did read but am  very unsure about the instruction since I am in 18.04. Is there not a more simple way since the 18.04 update?

Thank you very much.

Comment: problem solved - I simply booted up with the ubuntu 18.04 thumb drive in "try me mode" per advised after gparted was previously installed  in regular bootup of the OS. Launched gparted and it was very easy. However it was a little worrisome with the warnings that I might lose every thing. But was careful to "expand the right partition" and everything is good. 

I am very thankful for this site. Problem solved. Thanks!!